# How to calculate Day’s Value Change?

Tags: c#, yahoo-finance

I am trying to **calculate the  stock index 
Day’s Value Change**  as explained here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37550/Stock-quote-and-chart-from-Yahoo-in-C

How does one calculate this in C#?

Comment: link you posted ... shows example in C# only. what particular you are looking for?

Comment: I just highlighted in bold what I am after

Comment: Please inline what portion of that long article contains explanation of "calculate the stock index Day’s Value Change". So far it this question does not meet SO guidelines on not posting links as questions. Also avoid all sorts of thankyou notes/new here/searched a lot as such remarks generally don't add *information* to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reworking the GetQuote method from the article... if you pass in the symbol to this method it will return the Days Value Change.

```
public string GetDaysValueChange(string symbol)
{
    // Set the return string to null.
    string result = null;            
    try
    {
        // Use Yahoo finance service to download stock data from Yahoo
        //  Note that f=w1 tells the service we just want the Days Value Change
        string yahooURL = @"http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=" + 
                          symbol + "&f=w1";

        // Initialize a new WebRequest.
        HttpWebRequest webreq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(yahooURL);
        // Get the response from the Internet resource.
        HttpWebResponse webresp = (HttpWebResponse)webreq.GetResponse();
        // Read the body of the response from the server.
        StreamReader strm = 
          new StreamReader(webresp.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.ASCII);

        result = strm.ReadLine().Replace("\"", "");
        strm.Close();
    }
    catch
    {
        // Handle exceptions.
    }
    // Return the stock quote data in XML format.
    return result;
}
```